# encrypt object as JSON format not working well

Tags: node.js, json, encryption, sha1, cryptojs

I try to encrypt data (json format) with crypto,

**Here is my code:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let data = {
    aaa: "aaa",
    bbb: "bbb"};

let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
 encrypt(jsonData);

function encrypt(data) {
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'abc');
    console.log(data);
    hmac.update(data);
    let key = hmac.digest('hex');
    console.log(key);
}
```

**log:**

```
{
  "aaa": "aaa",
  "bbb": "bbb"
}
820c9d3d82a9a8fc1cc0352929ccccdfd945c5d0
```

When I copy the data from the log and paste it in [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output), I get another signature :

[image]

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: In the website you use carriage returns, while `JSON.stringify` will be a oneliner.

Comment: @ArthurAttout, So what should I use instead of JSON.stringify?

Comment: @ArthurAttout it's only a one-line if the third param is zero, if it's 1 or greater,linefeeds and spaces are added

Comment: HMAC is not encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, as soon as I added:

```
.replace (/\n/ g, '\r\n')
```

It worked fine.

Here is the fixed code :

```
function encrypt(data) {
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'abc');
    console.log(data);
    hmac.update(data.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n'));
    let key = hmac.digest('hex');
    console.log(key);
    console.log("#################################################");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all linebreaks and spaces:

```
{"aaa":"aaa","bbb":"bbb"}
```

the website will calculate a hash of:

```
61b23e04f44fd7dcfcfe9acf5fcb9381179538f7
```

which is identical to the result you will get in your program when you set the third param to 0.

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 0);
```

So the problem was different input for the hash function.

Comment: I don't want to remove linebreaks and spaces, I have a purpose in that it is JSON

Comment: Why is it useful for you to keep those line breaks ? This only creates more potential problems, the website maybe auto formats the newline with carriage returns AND line feed. Maybe it also uses tabs instead of 4 spaces. Or 1 space at all. A oneliner gets rid of all of these problems.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate with another site that does encrypt, so that's the limit and I have to keep the  linebreaks and spaces

Comment: Arthur Attout mentioned reasons why the result can be different and I have also demonstrated that the results are correct and just based on different input. After all your question was "what is wrong?". But I won't spent my time now to find a website that produces exact same results.